# How to set default data in data table multiple page

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatable

I have a problem with the default settings in the data table.
I want the checkbox to be checked on the controller side.
I found that checked in check box is not working after the second page onwards.

```
 function cteate_table() {
    var newRow = ''
    $('#main-table').dataTable()
    $('#main-table').dataTable().fnClearTable()
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        newRow += '<tr>'
        newRow += '<td>'
        newRow += i
        newRow += '</td>'
        newRow += '<td>'
        newRow += i + i + ' ' + '100'
        newRow += '</td>'
        newRow += '<td>'
        newRow += '<input type="checkbox" id="ch_"+i  name="ch_"+i>'
        newRow += '</td>'
        newRow += '</tr>'
        table = $('#main-table').DataTable();
        table.rows.add($(newRow)).draw();
    }
}

<table class="table table-bordered" id='main-table'>
   <thead>
      <tr class="thead_table">
         <th class="thead_id_list">index</th>
         <th class="thead_id" >example</th>
         <th class="thead_id2">Operation</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why $('#main-table').dataTable() appear many times  in the function . Check it!

Comment: It should be a comment